# HDD IO errors, is this definitely a HDD failure or could it be something else? kernel.log

Tags: linux, power-supply, hardware-failure, hard-drive-failure

**This HDD's history**

The hard drive is 1.5TB, 6 years old. IIRC it's 7200RPM with a ATA133 interface, using the motherboard's onboard controller. It gave perfect service in a big desktop PC, then 1 year ago I moved it to a mini-itx TVPC with a little Celeron G530 2.4ghz and basically nothing else, booting up daily for movies/browsing for 1 year without any issue, then suddenly one day it could not boot, giving disk IO errors.

The TVPC has continued daily service using a Linux live USB.

Now a month later, I scanned the hard drive using `badblocks -svw /dev/sda`

It completed

- 100% write pass
- 100% read pass
- 62% of writing some other patterm (..5C.. or something IIRC) the last time I checked while it was going perfectly.

All with a 0/0/0 error count.

The next time I checked, the first two error counts in badblocks were very high, (a few hundred k and a few 10k) but it was running in `screen` with a limited buffer so I couldn't scroll back far enough to see where the problem started.

I tried to check the drive's SMART stats with hdparm but saw that the drive had disappeared completely! `fdisk -l` did not show it anymore. Even after rebooting, the hard drive does not appear. I did this remotely so I can't power it down at the moment. But I suspect it will probably reappear after power cycling.

This is kernel.log when things suddenly went bad:

```
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x2000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/80:c8:80:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 25 ncq 65536 in        
         res 41/40:80:cf:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a 80 0 0 80 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250959         
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x300 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000001             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/40:40:a8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq 32768 in        
         res 41/40:40:cf:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/80:48:e8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq 65536 in        
         res 41/04:40:cf:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x1 (device error) 
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { ABRT }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a a8 0 0 40 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250959         
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x801000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/80:60:e8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 12 ncq 65536 in        
         res 41/40:80:eb:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a e8 0 0 80 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250987         
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x80 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:38:c8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:cf:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a c8 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250959         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281369, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x80000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:98:c8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:cf:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a c8 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250959         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281369, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:00:c8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:cf:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a c8 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250959         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281369, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:60:c8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 12 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:cf:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a c8 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250959         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281369, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:c0:d0:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:d1:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a d0 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250961         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281370, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x20 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:28:d0:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:d1:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a d0 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250961         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281370, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x20000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:88:d0:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:d1:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a d0 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250961         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281370, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x20000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:e8:d0:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 29 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:d1:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#29 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#29 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#29 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#29 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a d0 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250961         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281370, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x400 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:50:d8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:d8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a d8 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250968         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281371, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x100000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:a0:d8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:d8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a d8 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250968         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281371, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x8 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:18:d8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:d8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a d8 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250968         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281371, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x8000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:78:d8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:d8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#15 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#15 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#15 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#15 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a d8 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250968         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281371, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x8000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:d8:e0:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 27 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:e7:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a e0 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250983         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281372, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x100 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:40:e0:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:e7:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a e0 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250983         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281372, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x20000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:88:e0:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:e7:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a e0 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250983         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281372, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x2 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:08:e0:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:e7:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a e0 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250983         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281372, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x2000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:68:e8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 13 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:eb:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a e8 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250987         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281373, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x2000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:c8:e8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 25 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:eb:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a e8 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250987         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281373, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x40 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:30:e8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:eb:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a e8 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250987         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281373, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x40000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:90:e8:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq 4096 in        
         res 41/40:08:eb:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }          
ata1.00: error: { UNC }           
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133            
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]     
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed   
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a e8 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250987         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281373, async page read    
ata1: EH complete             
ata1.00: READ LOG DMA EXT failed, trying unqueued        
ata1: failed to read log page 10h (errno=-5)        
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x40000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0      
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008             
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED          
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:f0:f0:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq 4096 in        
         res 40/00:f0:f0:5a:59/00:00:58:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error) 
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }           
ata1.00: both IDENTIFYs aborted, assuming NODEV          
ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-2)            
ata1: hard resetting link            
ata1: SATA link up 3 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)      
ata1.00: both IDENTIFYs aborted, assuming NODEV          
ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-2)            
ata1: hard resetting link            
ata1: SATA link up 3 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)      
ata1.00: both IDENTIFYs aborted, assuming NODEV          
ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-2)            
ata1.00: disabled              
ata1: EH complete             
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a f0 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250992         
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 185281374, async page read    
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK        
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 CDB: Read(10) 28 0 58 59 5a f0 0 0 8 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1482250992         

(this last error repeated infinitely)
```

**The big question**

Any ideas why it was perfectly functional at the start of the test (completing a full write cycle, then a full read cycle, then 62% of some other cycle) then some hours later disappeared? Seems like maybe the HDD and motherboard is okay, but power supply or something else could be faulty?

One theory I have is that the power supply's ripple (noise) becomes too high with high-current-draw (using hard drive) but seems to manage with just a USB flash drive :/

Comment: ATA has died more than a decade ago, how on earth there exists a 1.5TB ATA drive?

Comment: The most likely cause is hard drive dying if old age (and your tests may have pushed it over the edge). It could conceivably be the controller on the motherboard. I'd be astonished if this was due to RAM, PSU or CPU.

Answer (score 1):

All we know right now is that there is a hardware problem.  It could be caused by the CPU (possibly because of overheat), the on-board ATA controller, the data cable, the power supply or the hard drive itself.

Since the simplest to check is the CPU's temperature, that's where I'd start.  Although this type of error being caused by CPU overheat is less common today, I've seen it numerous times on older machines.

If the CPU temperature is OK, you should probably try a different data cable or install the hard drive in another computer to see if it works properly.

Finally, if the issue is still not clarified, you may have to try a separate ATA controller or power supply to finalize the diagnostic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think it's a CPU heat problem as it's winter right now, but I'll ask the user to keep an eye on it.
# sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +32.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 0:         +31.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 1:         +27.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)

Comment: With such a low temperature right now, that doesn't seem like your problem