# Error after update - HP-Pavilion dv7 w/ Ubuntu 16.04 LTS & Vista

Tags: ubuntu

I have an issue similar to [HDD IO errors, is this definitely a HDD failure or could it be something else? kernel.log](https://superuser.com/questions/1102566/hdd-io-errors-is-this-definitely-a-hdd-failure-or-could-it-be-something-else-k)

This is the 2nd time it has occurred after an update and message stated computer needed to be restarted to finish installing update.

1st time I wiped the 2 ubuntu partitions and re-installed Ubuntu 16.04. System performed fine. Computer was shutdown a few times and started later without any issue.  Updates to addition programs and apps installed just fine including the updates where a restart was necessary.

This time, during the reboot, I took snapshots with my camera to assist with obtaining possible help.

Please be advised issue is not an overheating problem.

Also, do not believe it is a loose cable or hard drive failure since I can access Vista.

The only common characteristic is the issue occurred after an update when a re-start was required.

Have no idea what the 130 and 134 numbers are toward the bottom of the screen shots where the issue begins but if its an IP address it around Portland, Oregon.

Regardless, is there anyone that can offer a suggestion as to what is causing the issue (beside the update) and/or a possible fix?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I/O error, dev sda, sector 455008592, the hard drive has failing sector(s) you are best to  replace the Hard Drive with a new one.

Comment: The hd is fine. Still boots up and can select Vista from the GRUB. Ran diagnostics on the drive from advance option on GRUB which confirmed HD is fine. Its something to do with the update that was installed.

Comment: There are some sectors on hd which are not fine. Especially: 455008592. This is fact. I've a bunch of hdds with a fully working first half with a booting os, and a crappy full of badsector second half /home. It is quite normal when not all sectors are bad. This is how a hdd slowly go bad in the 99% of cases with more and more i/o errors. Run `smartctl --test=long /dev/sda`, then `smartctl -a /dev/sda` and see it yourself.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh! I see it now. I/O error, dev sda, sector 455008592 in two places. Running one more test and then gonna price a new HD as I enjoy ubuntu more than Windows.  Thank you very much for your assistance and educating me. As you can probably tell, I know NOTHING about the code that I posted. Just knew if I could there would be a better chance of resolving the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Primary Hard Disk Self Test (result) #10008) - Replace Hard Disk 1

Comment: Next time read carefully the error message! :-> (and who vote negative for my answer?)

Comment: Installed replacement hard drive and then Windows 7. Working on installing Ubuntu 16.04. Cannot thank Ipor Sircer enough.